# Why does iOS UIAlertController break when the message gets too long?

Tags: ios, string, uialertcontroller

The **UIAlertController** comes with a built in scrolling functionality, but if the string you set as the UIAlertController's message is too long, it shows nothing at all.  It still scrolls as if there is a long string there, but the message itself is blank.  Why is there a maximum length / what is the issue here?

This first image has 275 lines and it scrolls and displays the string fine.

[image]

This second image has 550 lines (twice as many) and although it still scrolls, the message is blank.

[image]

Comment: `UIAlertController` is not the proper tool for showing so much text. It's meant for short little messages.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the reply.  why does it come with the scrolling functionality if it's not meant to display long string?  it seems like the perfect means to display a Terms of Use and have the user agree to it - what is a better method?  and even if it's not the proper method, why does it break...what is happening that prevents it from displaying a long string?

Comment: It's probably a limit on how big a `UILabel` can be.

Comment: @rmaddy I see.  What is the better option for displaying  a Terms of Use that the user must agree to?

Comment: Probably a custom view controller. Look for other examples and see what they do.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this, too, but I think (not 100% sure) it's only in the simulator. I can't compare apples to apples (pun totally intended) because my real device is an iPod Touch, but even with 2000+ lines, it renders on the iPod Touch, but not in any of the simulators.

Comment: Thanks, this helped save me from headache... I just had to debug on actual devices to see the text. The simulator just showed blank but the real devices showed text.